# Copying files over the network using Batch File

Tags: batch-file, networking, cmd, xcopy

```
@ECHO OFF

set /p TerminalName= Enter the PC you wish to relocate ECFs on: 

ECHO Do you wish to relocate the ECFs on %TerminalName% ?

PAUSE

IF NOT EXIST "\\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google" (

ECHO You don't have Google installed

) ELSE (

ECHO You have Google installed!
ECHO Relocating the ECF Files! Here we go...

    IF EXIST "\\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google" (

    ECHO The ECF Folder already exists..
    ECHO Moving ECFs now

    cd \\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google
    FOR %%f IN (*.ecf) DO move /y "%%f" "\\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google" 


    ) ELSE (

    ECHO No ECF Folder exists...Let's sort that out!
    MKDIR "\\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google"

    cd \\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google
    ECHO Moving ECFs now
    FOR %%f IN (*.ecf) DO move /y "%%f" "\\%TerminalName%\c$\Program Files\Google" 
    )

)


ECHO Finished!

PAUSE
```

Whenever running the above Batch file i get this error:

CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.

Ps - Sorry for the formatting...it won't all go into the grey for code :(

Comment: try to map the unc patsh with `net use`

Comment: @npocmaka will NET Use be able to pick up the variable as it will change depending on the remote terminal name?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch code which should work for your task:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /P "TerminalName=Enter the PC you wish to relocate ECFs on: "
ECHO Do you wish to relocate the ECFs on !TerminalName! ?
PAUSE

SET "SourcePath=\\RemoteComputer\\c$\Program Files\Google\ECF_Folder"
SET "TargetPath=\\!TerminalName!\c$\Program Files\Google"

IF NOT EXIST "!TargetPath!" (
    ECHO You don't have Google installed.
    GOTO EndMoveECF
)

ECHO You have Google installed!
ECHO Relocating the ECF files! Here we go...

IF EXIST "%TargetPath%\ECF_Folder" (
    ECHO The ECF folder already exists..
) ELSE (
    ECHO No ECF Folder exists... Let's sort that out!
    MKDIR "%TargetPath%\ECF_Folder"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO Failed to create ECF folder "%TargetPath%\ECF_Folder".
        GOTO EndMoveECF
    )
)
ECHO Moving ECF files now ...
MOVE /Y "%SourcePath%\*" "%TargetPath%\ECF_Folder\"
ECHO Finished!

:EndMoveECF
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

You need to set `SourcePath` accordingly. And you need to replace all occurrences of `ECF_Folder` by whatever is right in your environment.

Moving the files is done with command **MOVE** without switching current working directory as this is not needed. And command **MOVE** supports also wildcards and therefore no need for a **FOR** loop.

Delayed environment variable expansion is used partly in case of user of batch file enters an invalid terminal name containing for example a double quote, angle brackets or other characters with a special meaning in batch files. Open a command prompt window and execute in this window `set /?` for details about delayed expansion.

There is once `!TerminalName!` and once `!TargetPath!` used instead of `%TerminalName%` and `%TargetPath%`. After existence of Google directory on remote computer is positive verified, it should be safe to reference `TargetPath` without delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CD`, the `PUSHD` command can be used. Remember, that internally `PUSHD` will do a `NET USE` and consume a "drive letter" from the OS. If this is done too many times, the system will run out of "drive letters."

Remember to `POPD` at an appropriate time.

UPDATE: Looking at this again, I doubt if you ever need to change directories. Where do the files exist that are to be `MOVE`'d to the new directory? More analysis needs to be done.

Comment: Hi @Paul - They will be moving from \\RemoteLocation1(Variable)\\c$\Program Files\Google to \\RemoteLocation2(Variable)\\c$\Program Files\Google